# How to get parent node with xpath using simpleXML (php)

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, ancestor

I have problems with an XML file.

Here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
<sheetPr codeName="Feuil3">
    <tabColor rgb="FF00B050"/>
</sheetPr>
<dimension ref="A18"/>
<sheetViews>
    <sheetView tabSelected="1" topLeftCell="A3" workbookViewId="0">
        <selection activeCell="A3" sqref="A3"/>
    </sheetView>
</sheetViews>
<sheetFormatPr baseColWidth="10" defaultRowHeight="15"/>
    <cols>
        <col min="1" max="1" width="29.140625" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/>
        <col min="2" max="2" width="24.42578125" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/>
        <col min="3" max="3" width="14.28515625" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/>
        <col min="4" max="4" width="5.42578125" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/>
        <col min="5" max="5" width="6.140625" bestFit="1" customWidth="1"/>
    </cols>

<sheetData>
    <row r="18" ht="16.5" customHeight="1"/>
</sheetData>
<sortState ref="A2:E1036">
    <sortCondition descending="1" ref="C1"/>
</sortState>
<pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

I would like to have the parent node (row) with this xpath restrictions (that work) :

```
$row2 = $xml->xpath("//*[local-name()='row']/@*[local-name()='r' and .= '18']");
```

For now it returns me this :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#383 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["r"]=>
      string(2) "18"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have the parent.. (row)

How should I do ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andersson Nope, it doesn't work.. :(

Comment: You are selecting the attribute. I guess you will have to use "and" to filter for the attribute value.

Comment: This doesn't work : //*[local-name()='row' and 'r' = '18']

Comment: I meant more like "/sheetData/row[@r='18']"

Comment: @Fildor, I got problems with namespace.. so it return empty

Comment: I see. Can you chose another name for the namespace?

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include the sample XML as text, rather than an image (removing irrelevant sections to keep it short). Then we can test our suggestions without having to type out all that by hand!

Comment: @IMSoP It's done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On thing first. To get rid of the `local-name()` and stop ignoring the namespace, register a prefix for it. After that it is just a simple condition.

```
$worksheet = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$worksheet->registerXpathNamespace(
  'm', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main'
);

var_dump(
  $worksheet->xpath('//m:row[@r=18]')
);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["r"]=>
      string(2) "18"
      ["ht"]=>
      string(4) "16.5"
      ["customHeight"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will always return an array. Here could be several or no `row` element. Use an condition to validate that you fetched a node or use a loop to iterate over the array.

The expression in this case contains of two parts: `//m:row` fetch any `row` element node in the document. `[]` contains filter conditions for the found nodes. In this case `@id=18`, the attribute node `id` should equal `18`.